# get_feature_names() is not working for a sparse matrix made using CountVectorizer() of sikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix, countvectorizer

I am working on the Amazon fine food review dataset and after all the preprocessing I am trying to use the CountVectorizer() function on my data (in the panda data frame) and I want to know the names of the columns of the sparse matrix but when i am using the get_feature_names() function it gives an error saying
"AttributeError: get_feature_names not found"

here's the code

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
count_vec = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2))
bigram_count = count_vec.fit_transform(data["CleanedText"].values)
print(bigram_count.get_feature_names())
```

in the code data["CleanedText"] is a panda data frame column having all the preprocessed words of a particular review
this is the error i am getting

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-db82ffbaf8ba> in <module>
----> 1 print(bigram_count.get_feature_names())

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py in __getattr__(self, attr)
    687             return self.getnnz()
    688         else:
--> 689             raise AttributeError(attr + " not found")
    690 
    691     def transpose(self, axes=None, copy=False):

AttributeError: get_feature_names not found
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `.get_feature_names()` on a sparse matrix because it's not an attribute of a sparse matrix.

It's an attribute of the `CountVectorize` object. Call `count_vec.get_feature_names()` instead.